# Bug Tracking Schema

Tags: bug-tracking

I'm looking to implement my own bug tracking database.  Could somebody point me to the database table layout diagrams of any of the many tracking databases already in existance.  I've come up with most of my requirements, and its simple for the most part, but I want to get an idea of what other people thought was important and how exactly they accomplished certain objectives.

Comment: "I'm looking to implement my own bug tracking database" - surely that's reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Mitch: sometimes, nobody else's wheel gets you across the terrain you have to cross in the style in which you wish to travel. NASA have reinvented the wheel a number of times for use on Mars!

Comment: @Tom Anderson: The fact is: if you think you need to write something from scratch, more often than not, there is already something available...

Comment: @Mitch: true. What brought me to this question is that i'm also thinking about writing a story/task/bug tracker, and it's precisely because i can't find anything that already exists that does what i want. Bug tracking seems like a field where there are a lot of players, but not a lot of diversity; lots of good road wheels, but nothing for cross-country use.

Answer (score 2):

FogBugz has the ability to let you export your bug database in a MySQL or SQL Server format. You could then look at the export and see how the data is structured.

I'm sure there will be missing tables that are built in to the app, but this will give you a starting point.

The other option would be to simply go look at the code for the numerous OSS bug tracking options out there and see how they do it. Trac and Bugzilla would be a good place to start.

(hell, simply installing either of those and looking at the DB structure with something like PHPMyAdmin would probably take all of an hour and should give you a great place to start)